# What browsers are compatible with Adobe Flash Plugin?

Tags: browser, adobe-flash

Even if Flash Player on Android is no more supported by Adobe, it is still very easy to obtain it (eg, via Aptoide). The problem is that Chrome is not compatible with it. On my Galaxy Note 10 I can use it with the stock browser (it works like a charm). Unfortunately my friend has a Nexus 7 Tablet. We were successfull at installing flash but we can't find any browser that supports it (we tried Dolphin).

Any recommendations?

Comment: In reality, almost any browser besides Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firefox - it has goot support of web technologies, but it has big memory consumption.
2. Standard Android browser (it not available on Nexuses with Android 4.1 and higher).
3. Opera **Mobile** (**not Opera Mini**) - it has "specific" support of some web technologies, but normal resources consumption.

Comment: [Opera Mobile 12.1](http://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/android/mobile/1210/) was the last version of Opera Mobile which used the proprietary Presto rendering engine. [Opera 14](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/opera-14-for-android-is-out) now uses the same WebKit engine as Chrome, and eats memory just as well.

Comment: I installed 12 on my nexus 5 but still no flash sound on www.micromusic.net

Answer (score 0):

Try FlashFox for flash support:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.browser.flashfox

Answer (score 0):

Go install Dolphin, head to their labs and install flash. Its what I use on my Nexus 7.